# Populating collection_select field on selection of another collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two collection_select field in my form. One is to select category and the other is to select subcategory. I want the subcategory field to populate as per the category gets selected. I someone select category 1 then the subcategories belong to category 1 will be populated in the second collection_select field. I'm not sure what to do. What modifications I need in the following code I tried.

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :name) %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :subcategory_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select(:subcategory_id, Subcategory.where(category_id: :category_id), :id, :name) %>
</div>
```

Comment: You need ajax to populate the other collection based on whats selected in category.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

Use jquery. Something like that -

```
$(select_category).on('change', function(){ update_subcategory_options() })
```

where update_subcategory_options() - ajax request or another code.

Or use collection select with group (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/option_groups_from_collection_for_select)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ajax to get this functionality

Try this Example:

**form.html.erb**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(fnction(){
   $('#category_id').change(function(){
       var value = $(this).val()
       $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'options',
          data: {id: value},
          success: function(data){
            $('#subcategory').html(data)
          }
       })
   })
})
</script>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :name) %>
</div>
<div id="subcategory"></div>
```

**controller:**

```
def options
     id = params[:id]
     @subcategory = Subcategory.where(:category_id => id)
     render :partial => 'options'
end
```

**_options.html.erb:**

```
<%= f.label :subcategory_id %><br>
```

change this line

```
<%= f.collection_select(:subcategory_id, @subcategory, :id, :name) %>
```

to

```
<%= f.input :subcategory_id, @subcategory %>
```

and finally in **Routes.rb**

```
post '/options' => 'categories#options'
```

Comment: its not working for some reason. No subcategory select field being generated. I followed all the steps you mentioned.